# SQL Query to display table columns items in a column?

Tags: mysql, count, distinct

I have a table in a database like below:

```
-----------------------------
| ID | Item1 | Item2 | Item3|
-----------------------------
| 1  | A1    | B3    | C1   |
| 2  | A2    | B3    | C2   |
| 3  | A1    | B2    | C2   |
| 4  | A2    | B1    | C1   |
-----------------------------
```

And I want to display the table items with its count like below:

```
---------------
| item | count|
---------------
| A1   | 2    | 
| A2   | 2    |
| B1   | 1    |
| B2   | 1    |
| B3   | 2    |
| C1   | 2    |
| C2   | 2    |
---------------
```

Is it possible? If it is, how's the query? So far I only managed to display it one by one foreach item like this:

```
------------------  
| Item1  | Count |  
------------------
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Count` , `Item1` FROM `table` GROUP BY `Item1`; 

------------------  
| Item2  | Count |  
------------------
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Count` , `Item2` FROM `table` GROUP BY `Item2`;

------------------  
| Item3  | Count |  
------------------
SELECT COUNT(*) AS `Count` , `Item3` FROM `table` GROUP BY `Item3`;
```

Comment: First normalise your schema

Comment: should be OK @Strawberry. If he has 5 items for ID #1, he can have 2 rows, with Item1 and Item2 filled in for second one, no ?

Comment: just kidding Jess, clean up the schema. If you want to know how just ask

Comment: @Strawberry - Drew Is it a must to normalise the database? I'll try the answer from Gordon 1st. Thanks.

Comment: Yes. I'm sorry to say but I think Gordon's answer is disingenuous. That said, his answer contains a clue about what a normalised design might look like, and how you might go about transforming your design.

Comment: @Strawberry The solution from Gordon works, thanks however.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `union all` and `group by`:

```
select item, count(*)
from ((select item1 as item from `table`) union all
      (select item2 as item from `table`) union all
      (select item3 as item from `table`)
     ) t
group by item
order by item;
```

Comment: Thanks, @GordonLinoff